# Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined bot

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put an option in a bot and I get the error when I run the command. !ddd is the command

```js
obterInfoDDD: async(DDD)=>{
    try {
        const githubGistDDD= await axios.get(" here I put the github directory ddd.json")
        const estados = githubGistDDD.data.estados
        const indexDDD = estados.findIndex(estado => estado.ddd.includes(DDD))
        if(indexDDD != -1){
            var resposta = criarTexto(msgs_texto.utilidades.ddd.resposta, estados[indexDDD].nome, estados[indexDDD].regiao)
            return resposta
        } else {
            throw new Error(msgs_texto.utilidades.ddd.nao_encontrado)
        }
    } catch(err){
        var errors = [msgs_texto.utilidades.ddd.nao_encontrado]
        if(!errors.includes(err.message)){
            consoleErro(err.message, "API obterInfoDDD")
            throw new Error(msgs_texto.utilidades.ddd.erro_servidor)
        } else {
            throw err
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably `estados` is `undefined`. Debug your code and inspect the `estados` contents. Use `console.dir(estados);` to show the object properties in the console.

Comment: Nothing appears: /

Comment: what does `await axios.get()` call return? type `console.log("1111111111");` before this call, and `console.dir(githubGistDDD);` after this call. And inspect, what happens and what is being returned.

Comment: I could already solve it, it was wrong the github link had one, too many. Thanks

Comment: Post converted to comment for @ch4za: How could you solve it? I am using the same API and I am also from Argentina.